# Magento 2: I want to change Item collection sequence on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, price, cart-items

I want to change cart sequence on cart page Price ascending wise. Please share a page link item collection for cart page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plugin for this

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin name="append_order_by" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

**Vendor\Module\Plugin\Quote.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Quote
{

    public function afterGetItemsCollection($subject, $collection)
    {
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->order('price ASC');
        //$select->order('row_total ASC'); // If you want to set as per row total
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have got the error: Plugin class  Magento\Checkout\Plugin\Quote doesn't exist

Comment: You need to create a new module for same or place this code in your existing custom module if you have.

Comment: `Vendor\Module\` should be replaced with your new module name.

Comment: Small mistake from me. Thanks Its working fine.

Comment: I have added in default Magento_Checkout Module. It is working fine.